# fabricJs to toSvg causing trouble for textbox

Tags: svg, fabricjs

I am using `fabricJs` `textbox` like this,

```
var text = 'Type Text Here';

    var textSample = new fabric.Textbox(text, {
        left: 200,
        top: 70,
        width: 200,
        height: 20,
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
        fontWeight: '',
        fontSize: parseInt('25'),
        originX: 'center',
        hasRotatingPoint: true,
        centerTransform: true,
    });

    canvas.add(textSample);
```

and when i do,

```
fabric.log('SVG output with viewBox attribute: ', canvas.toSVG({
            viewBox: {
                x: 50,
                y: 50,
                width: 250,
                height: 250
            }
        }));
```

It creates span like this,

```
<tspan x="-100" y="7.87" fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Type Text Here</tspan>
```

that is okay, but if i change text within that textbox and again if i generate svg will look like this,

```
<text font-family="Helvetica" font-size="25" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" >
        <tspan x="-100" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">t</tspan>
        <tspan x="-93" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">e</tspan>
        <tspan x="-79" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">s</tspan>
        <tspan x="-66" y="7.87" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">t</tspan>
    </text>
```

It will generate `<tspan`> for every text, which is causing trouble while writing `svg` in `tcpdf`. It shows wrong spacing between text in `pdf`.

Is it bug or default behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Textbox extends i-text, and i-text saves every letter by itself so that you can change colors on each letter individually.

Regular text saves a textblock instead. Try using text:

```
var text = 'Type Text Here';

var textSample = new fabric.Text(text, {
    left: 200,
    top: 70,
    width: 200,
    height: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontWeight: '',
    fontSize: parseInt('25'),
    originX: 'center',
    hasRotatingPoint: true,
    centerTransform: true,
});

canvas.add(textSample);
```

Answer (score -3):

You're using itext.
Try using regular text

Comment: I may not be familiar with fabricjs, but I cannot see the word `itext` anywhere in the question.

Comment: i am not using iText here

Comment: Yes you are... see above answer.